# Windows 7 partition unreadable

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

Hello recently my windows 7 partition stopped working. I found this out when I loaded up windows 7 and attempted to log in but failed. So I booted up Linux and looked a t gparted to find the error from the partition. Is there anyway to mend this problem or at least get my files from the windows side.

```
 Unable to read the contents of this file system!
 Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
 The cause might be a missing software package.
 The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file  '
 system support:  ntfsprogs / ntfs-3g.
```

other information:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/jqLbQb3.png]

Comment: Do you have ntfs-3g installed in linux ?

Answer (score 1):

Like user22846a5165asdf98 asked, this error just looks like your Linux can't read NTFS which isn't uncommon. You can try that software package that will allow it to read NTFS hopefully. However, I would recommend you make a clone of your drive before attempting anything else since that's the safest thing to do and would let you try things without fear of causing more harm ([instructions with ddrescue](http://datarecovery.com/rd/how-to-clone-hard-disks-with-ddrescue/)). ddrescue will also allow you to work around bad sectors if there are any - and it's possible that caused this issue in the first place and maybe the ntfs error. Beyond that, [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is reputed to be helpful with fixing Windows partitions so I'd give that a try. Then I'd check your drive's SMART data to see info about its health as there is a possibility of bad sectors. Increasing bad sectors means you need to get a new drive.

You also have less attractive options of raw file recovery software to get most of your files back, but don't jump to that yet. And of course using a data recovery company. So all is not lost.